# How to read averaged nodal stress from abaqus odb file using python script?

Tags: python, abaqus, stress, odb

I know how to read element or element node stress value (unaveraged) using python script.

```
field = stressField.getSubset(region=topCenter,position=INTEGRATION_POINT, elementType = 'CAX4')
```

But i want averaged stress values at nodes. FYI, my odb does not contain node position data for stress (i.e., position=NODAL).

Comment: If you specify `position=NODAL`, Abaqus should interpolate the values from INTEGRATION_POINT.

Comment: hi @hgazibara, thanks for your reply. but it does not work. I get empty array when i use position=NODAL.

Comment: How did you define `region`? Is it an element set, node set, ...?

Comment: Yes i defined region with a nodeset.

Answer (score 0):

this is one of those things that way more cumbersome than it should be.
you need to create  xydata :

```
session.xyDataListFromField(odb=odb,
        outputPosition=ELEMENT_NODAL,
        variable=(( 'S', INTEGRATION_POINT), ),
        elementSets=('PART-1-1.SETNAME', ))
```

this creates a dictionary with objects for every node of every element and every stress component (ie. huge).  Unfortunately the dictionary is keyed by cumbersome descriptor strings, eg:

```
 session.xyDataObjects['S:S11 PI:PART-1-1 E: 15 N:2'].data
```

gives the 11 stress component of node 2 associated with element 15.  To make use of the data in a script you need to either construct the strings, or loop over the dictionary and parse the `positionDescription` for each object.

Edit: if you want the nodal averages its pretty much the same. You do:

```
session.xyDataListFromField(odb=odb,
        outputPosition=NODAL,
        variable=(( 'S', INTEGRATION_POINT), ),
        nodeSets=('PART-1-1.SETNAME', ))
```

and the dictionary objects are keyed like:

```
 session.xyDataObjects['S:S11 (Avg: 75%) PI:PART-1-1 N:2'].data
```

note you can issue multiple `session.xyDataListFromField` calls and all of the data goes into `xyDataObjects` (For example if you want stress and strain you can process both at once. )

For completeness, if you only want a specific component(s) you can request as:

```
 variable=(( 'S', INTEGRATION_POINT,((COMPONENT, 'S11'),)), )
```

Comment: Thanks @agentp, But i need unique nodal values. Is it possible to get the unique nodal stress values from odb display object?